# How to use RichFaces a4j:commandButton not using submit

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have an `a4j:commandButton` which looks like this

```
    <a4j:commandButton id="stopBtn" type="button" reRender="lastOp"
  action="#{MyBacking.stop}" value="Stop" />
 </a4j:commandButton>
```

When the app is deployed, and the button clicked, the stop() method is not being called.  All the `a4j:commandButton` examples refer to forms, but this button is not in a form - it's a button the user is going to use to cause the server to run some back-end logic.  At the moment, the method is

```
    public void stopNode() {
 logger.info("STOPPING");
 setLastOp("Stopped.");
}
```

Other methods which don't use this type of button are updating the lastOp field, but I'm not seeing anything on the console with this one.  Am I right to cast this as a button?  Should I put this in a `h:form` tag?

The firebug console says:

```
this._form is null
```

which I don't understand.

Any help well appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UICommand` components ought to be placed inside an `UIForm` component. So, your guess

> Should I put this in a `h:form` tag?

is entirely correct :) This because they fire a `POST` request and the only (normal) way for that is using a HTML `<form>` element whose `method` attribute is set to `"post"`. Firebug also says that a parent form element is been expected, but it resolved to `null` and thus no actions can be taken place.

Only "plain vanilla" links like `h:outputLink` and consorts doesn't need a form, because they just fires a `GET` request.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, wrap it in a form.  I'm sure BalusC will post a detailed explanation while I'm typing my answer. (yup, there it is)

I have to ask why you didn't just try a form first, before posting here.

Comment: To be honest, I was thinking of two things at once, and would have edited the question having tried it except the end of my working day came and I was out the door.  +1 for your observation..

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="stopBtn" type="button" reRender="lastOp" action="#{MyBacking.stop}" value="Stop" />
```

You finished `<a4j:commandButton` with `/>`, why need that orphan `</a4j:commandButton>` ?

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to place the button inside a form, you can do something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton onclick="fireAjax()"/>

<h:form>
   <a4j:jsFunction name="fireAjax" action=".."/>
</h:form>
```